# Materializecss: carousel & slider not working

Tags: html, css, joomla, materialize

EDIT: I found out the solution. See my post at the bottom of the page.

I've created a template for joomla with materializecss. Everything works fine except the slider (which displays as a gray rectangle) and carousel which just shows images one after another as obsolete divs.

The carousel:
[image: carousel]

The slider:
[image: slider]

I've imported the jquery script before materializecss. I've also called the carousel.carousel(). The code for slider and carousel I used is same as on the Materializecss website in examples. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating materializecss files solved the problem. I also found out that a part of materialize.css was missing.

Answer (score -1):

enter this script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel();
```

)}

Answer (score -1):

If you are using NOT default classes for carousel items - you need to change them classes in carousel.js file